# maven jar option, creating a additional jar during build

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

when trying to create a maven build, i need resouces soures jar, javadoc jar, and compiled classes jar, which is easily achieved through existing plugins.

But i do have  XSD's under `src/main/resources/xsd` folder, which i prefer to be created in a diffent jar during the build process, is it  possible?

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional artefacts to your maven build using either a custom plugin or as an [assembly](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-intro.html).  An assembly allows you to define any group of resources into a new artefact. This new artefact will be an 'attachement' to your existing one in the same way sources jars can be attached.

When creating an assembly you need to define a descriptor and put it somewhere like `src/main/assembly/xsd.xml`

The descriptor will look something like:

```
<assembly>
   <id>xsd</id>
   <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
   </formats>
   <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
           <directory>src/main/resources/xsd</directory>
           <includes>
               <include>*.xsd</include>
           </includes>
      </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The second part is the assembly plugin configuration which will look something like:

```
  <build>   
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/xsd.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>           
        </configuration>
        <executions>
              <execution>
              <id>make-xsd-zip</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This configuration should give you an artefact with the name: `<artifactid>-<version>-<assemblyid>.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Well, MAVEN natively does not supports multiple artifacts from a single `pom.xml`. But you can create another empty project with only a `pom` to create another jar

```
codebase
    |- pom.xml
    |- src
    |- xsdJar
        |- pom.xml
    |- [other stuff]
```

Now, in `xsdJar\pom.xml`,

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>../src/main/resources/xsd/*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Also, call the above mentioned module in your main `pom.xml`

```
<modules>
  <module>xsdJar</module>
</modules>
```